# Google Analytics Not Tracking Mobile Visitors

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A Google Analytics account I have access to seems to completely ignore visits from handheld devices.

I originally noticed as the traffic count from handheld was only 15, compared to the thousands received on desktop. I've visited the site from tablets and mobiles while viewing Realtime, and it doesn't show up.

I was worried that it was classing these visits as desktop, but it actually seems that they just aren't getting tracked at all.

I've also noticed that the URL structure is different to anything I've seen before. Instead of domain.com/services, it's services/domain.com - which is a 404 page. However it does appear that Analytics is tracking visits to the actual page, just displaying the URL incorrectly. Could these two issues be connected?

Comment: Check if you have any filters applied that would remove mobile/tablet traffic, and also that you don't have segment applied.

Comment: I've checked that. I've now noticed that the mobile visits aren't being tracked on other analytics tools I have set up, so it's not just Google. Could anything on the website be causing this?

Comment: One thing you could try to narrow down the problem is to open the URL with developer tools in mobile mode (F12 -> CTRL+SHIFT+M in Chrome Windows) and search for the **collect** gif in the network tab. Collect sends hits to the Google Analytics servers, hence the request header should return a 200 status code and the [query string parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) should specify if the send hit is valid.